# How do I search for an App in iOS11?

Tags: ios

In iOS10, by pulling on the Home Screen, I could search for an app. How do I do this in iOS11?

When I pull down from the Home screen, I see a message "Earlier Today" only. If I scroll down, nothing happens. If I scroll up, I see the Camera.app.

If I have a new message, that shows above the "Earlier Today" message.

Thanks for any help.

This is beta 2.

Edit... Adding a screenshot:

[image]

If I press Home, I see all my first page icons. If I then scroll up, I see the Control Panel. I can't seem to get a screenshot of this. It shows icons for brightness, and mini images of my open apps. I don't see a search option.

Comment: This still works. Scroll down the proposals. It's below them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Proposals" please?

Comment: If you start typing, results are shown for emails, visited websites, app store etc. (depending on what you configured in the settings). I called these results proposals. If scroll down, below you will a "search web" or similar. (I'm using the German version, so I can't exactly tell the words in English. )

Comment: Oh I see only now that you are using the beta. Sorry. Don't know for sure then.

Comment: @not iOS 11 is *only* in beta, what do you mean? App results are shown at the top in iOS 10 and 11, no need to scroll down.

Comment: If it's not configured, app results won't show. Maybe it's a configuration issue (General - Spotlight search). Re beta, I mixed up version numbers. Mea culpa.

Comment: [The meaning of the search setting has changed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299213/4395) in iOS 11, preventing many (or perhaps even for man users most) apps from appearing unless changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as iOS 10. Pull down on the home screen (from somewhere amongst the apps, not from the top of the display) and a search bar appears at the top. Type the name of the app you want to look for and the results show in the Siri App Suggestions section.

Comment: @David You're pulling down from the very top of the display. Instead, just pull down from somewhere in the middle of the home screen. Thanks for providing a screenshot, I've upvoted the question

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much! Could you post this as an answer please. I'm sure it will help lots of people.

Comment: @David Excellent, I've edited my answer

Comment: Ah okay. Thought you were seeing results, but not the ones you were looking for.

Comment: However, is that any different from ios 10?

Comment: I think it's different. On my wife's iOS10 device, if I scroll from the top of the Lock screen, I see the search options. It does appear to be the same from the App pages. So you are correct. It's just that my expected behavior did no longer works. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Does it really [work the same](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/299076/4395)?

Comment: @rax Yup, been using iOS 11 since the first beta and it does work the same!