# iOS 11: Allow searching for All Apps

Tags: search, siri, ios

Apparently iOS no longer automatically includes apps in the search. Frankly, that’s the only thing I ever search for.

According to the accepted answer in [Why is iOS unable to find my apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299076/why-is-ios-unable-to-find-my-apps), I need to turn on the feature for individual apps in the **Siri & Search** settings.

Is there a way of enabling *all* apps to be searched without enabling each individual app?

Comment: Have you disabled "Search & Siri Suggestions" for individual apps in Settings on your device?

Answer (score 1):

I was able the get the search setting for all apps turned on by turning off all Siri search features and then turning them back on again.